# How are homogeneity or heterogeneity of materials decided?

Tags: density, meteorology

How is the homogeneity or heterogeneity of materials decided?

What kind of measurement or assessment exists for inferring when e.g. the density of the material of an object is uniform across the object?

Answer (score 0):

[PDF]
A Modified Approach to Homogeneity Testing at …

www.icdd.com/resources/axa/vol42/V42_09.pdf

Here is one method that may suffice.

A new method is presented in this paper which is based both on the information mass concept and on modified statistical test procedures. With this approach the homogeneity assessment for all microanalytical techniques, including u-XRF, u-PIXE, u-SRXRF and EPMA...can be standardized. The method follows a general idea of homogeneity testing at bulk levels, and permits the assessment of homogeneity at mass scale from ng up to some mg.